# Laravel JWT Auth Invalidate token-Allow one Device at a time

Tags: laravel, jwt

In my Laravel API project, I want to To limit the number of concurrent login to one device at a time.(allow only one device at a time).

How can I achieve this?
I have tried to enable blacklisted to true but it seems to be not working..

```
 'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),
```

I want to invalidate the old token when the new token got generated or refreshed.

I Hope Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried getting all the old tokens and revoking them one by one except the current one? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Cerlin revoke old tokens

Comment: @JEJ found any solution for this case?

Comment: @AmarRatnaShakya yes

Comment: @JEJ Perhaps can you share your approach for the solution?